# Binary Search Tree output in postorder doesn't work

Tags: python

I have got this code from stackoverflow but it doesn't work well :

```
def postorder(tree):

    data = []

    def recurse(node):
        if not node:
            return
        recurse(node.left)
        recurse(node.right)
        data.append(node.data)

    recurse(tree)
    return data

a = input().split(' ')
recRoot = Node(a[0])
for i in range(len(a)):
    recRoot.insert(a[i])

print(postorder(recRoot))
```

- Input: 88 99 43 15 4 91 31
- Output: 31 4 15 43 91 99 88
- Output should be: 4 31 15 43 91 99 88

Please help me solve me this problem. THANK YOU 3 TIMES:))

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing with `Node()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with postorder function. I think you have change sign while creating the tree, do check your insert function again.

Comment: Thank you 3 times for your advice. It work well now :)